# MessagingCenter.Subscribe not triggered

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement `MessagingCenter` to send data from native to pcl.
In the native I set the send method:

`MessagingCenter.Send<Xamarin.Forms.Application>(App.Current, "Autorizzato");`

Here is the code from the main page:

```
protected override void OnStart()
       {  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Application>(this, "Autorizzato", (sender) => {                    
               Debug.WriteLine("Ok!");
          });
       }
```

The code is executed correctly, but `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` is not triggered.
The types of instances are both the same.

So, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code itself is fine, but you need to make sure that when you send the message, the `TSender` is already instantiated, not null.

Where did you call `MessagingCenter.Send` ?If you call it in `OnCreate` method of `MainActivity`,try move it to `OnStart` method.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart(); 
        MessagingCenter.Send<Xamarin.Forms.Application>(App.Current, "Autorizzato");
    }
{
```

then Subscribe in the `App.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
      
        InitializeComponent();          
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Application>(this, "Autorizzato", (sender) => {
           Debug.WriteLine("Ok!");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check my blog here: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/xamarin-forms-messagingcenter-ab97eb923fd0

It gives you detailed info on how to use XF messaging center.

How to subscribe:

```
Subscribe<TSender> (object subscriber, string message, Action<TSender> callback, TSender source = null)
```

So in the application, it would look something like:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Sender> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
// do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});
```

And your sender would be something like :

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi");
```

These changes should be good to make this work

In case of questions feel free to revert

Comment: I've already read your blog and I followed the tips.
Nevertheless, I believe the problem is the type of sender,
which is AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentActivity in the native project.
How can I specify the same type even in the Subscribe in the PCL project?

Comment: you can use `object` as the `<TSender>` parameter to avoid that

Comment: @jason: unfortunately it doesn't still triggered :(

Comment: are you using `<object>` for both Send and Subscribe?  The `<T>` parameters much match

Comment: Yes, I did, but nothing